# Handling button visibility in Flask with Jinja

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I'm relatively new to Flask and Jinja, the issue I have is more of a "best practice" question, as I can successfully achieve what I need to with what I know so far but it feels somewhat clunky. In addition, I've also stumbled by chance into a side effect that I wasn't expecting and which I'd like to be able to avoid completely in the first place.

I have a pretty standard `route` definition which renders a Jinja HTML page. On this page are a number of buttons that, depending on certain predetermined conditions, I would like to make them visible. This is what I've created so far:

```
@app.route('/some/route/')
def index(foo, bar):
    button = {
        'create': False,
        'update': False,
    }
    if foo:
        button['create'] = True
    if bar:
        button['update'] = True
    return render_template('index.html', button=button)
```

In Jinja:

```
<!-- Somewhere on the page, I might want to show this button -->
{% if button.create %}
    <button>Create</button>
{% endif %}

<!-- Somewhere else on the page, I might want to show this other button -->
{% if button.update %}
    <button>Update</button>
{% endif %}
```

Upon first glance, this should work just fine. But unfortunately, you might have spotted the issue: `.update` is a `built-in method update of dict object`, so although my `Create` button behaves as expected, my `Update` button is always visible.

So my thoughts are:

- Because of the risk of using reserved words for my button name, I'm going to have to namespace them, maybe change from `button.update` to `button.show_update`. I can do but it isn't quite as short and to the point as I would like.
- I don't really want to declare each button individually like `button_create` and `button_update` as then I'd have to pass each one individually to `render_template()` which would just be messy with loads of buttons and other data to feed the template.
- Is there just simply a better way of handling this kind of scenario in the first place that I'm not aware of? Or is Jinja full of these little *gotcha's*?

I have tried searching but nothing comes anywhere close to what I'm looking for... maybe I'm just overthinking this whole thing?...

Comment: I would try to assign button.name to 'create' or 'update' and simplify things in python and jinja?

Comment: @gittert I'm afraid I don't understand what you're suggesting, would you be able to give a single line example?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while for me working with flask, but I would try something like this. I would get rid of the 2 if statements in your python code as well as in the jinja template. Bear in mind I have no knowledge of your application, but I'm sure you get the idea.
I used an else, which probably can be exchanged with elif or even if bar. whatever suits your needs.

```
 @app.route('/some/route/')
 def index(foo, bar):
     buttons = []

    if foo:
        buttons.append('create')
    if bar:
        buttons.append('update')

   return render_template('index.html', button = buttons)
```

In Jinja:

```
{% for button in buttons %}
    <button> {button} </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Gittert, unfortunately this doesn't really answer my question as this simply changes the label of a button, whereas what I am trying to achieve is to show/hide many buttons on a single page and I'm looking for a clean way to do it. Thank you all the same for your suggestion, I do appreciate it :)

Comment: see updated answer, with for loop. If necessary you could use a dict instead of a list if you want to pass more info per button.